# How is the G-test related to the Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, central-limit-theorem, likelihood-ratio

I remember having read that the G-test is a more accurate version of Pearson's $\chi^2$-test, and that both are derived directly from the Central Limit Theorem.

Unfortunately I cannot remember where I read that, nor how reliable this statement is. Intuitively, it makes sense, because both the G-test and the $\chi^2$-test are tested against the same distribution, the $\chi^2$ distribution.

Moreover, Wikipedia writes about the $\chi^2$ distribution that

> By the central limit theorem, because the chi-square distribution is the sum of $k$ independent random variables with finite mean and variance, it converges to a normal distribution for large $k$.

Where can I find some authoritative material that connects the G-test, the $\chi^2$-test, the $\chi^2$ distribution and the Central Limi Theorem? Proofs and explicit derivations of the formulas from first principles are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might begin with the discussion on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test#Relation_to_the_chi-squared_test).

Comment: @whuber Thank you, that's where I read it! I recently looked for it and somehow didn't notice it on the G-test article. It is indeed an excellent starting point and the references are helpful.